# I am trying to make new linux process scheduler

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, scheduling

I downloaded the source code of linux kernel `5.7.3`. I already compiled it and installed it by the following commands:

```
make
make modules_install
make install
```

the kernel is added to grub2 and it is successfully working, however, I want to make my own cpu scheduler. My question is: how can I only compile and install the changes under `./kernel/sched/` folder without recompiling everything?

I know there is `make kernel/sched/` which only compile files under this folder, however, I am going to edit the code frequently and try it out. What is the best way to do this? If I edited a file under `kernel/sched/` should I run

```
make
make modules_install
make install
```

again? or there is a better and faster way to test my changes?

Note: the kernel is already installed and it is showing in grub2 menu and my system works when I select it, but I am going to change the code again and again and I need a faster way to test my changes.

Answer (score 2):

`make` is intelligent enough to allow to recompile only the new source files without recompiling everything. If the kernel still insists on recompiling pretty much everything (which is possible if your changes include the header files which are included by other source files), please use `ccache` (google for it).